# How to quote a list (for a scientific thesis)?

Tags: quotes, science

I would like to quote a list verbatim.

Let's say this is the list, and it's originally from a book:

1. Mathematics is essential in many fields, including natural science, engineering, medicine, finance, and the social sciences.
2. Mathematicians engage in pure mathematics (mathematics for its own sake) without having any application in mind, but practical applications for what began as pure mathematics are often discovered later.
3. Mathematicians seek and use patterns to formulate new conjectures; they resolve the truth or falsity of such by mathematical proof.

Now I want to use it word by word for my thesis. Do I need to add quotation marks? If yes, where?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a scientific thesis for publication, or as part of the requirements for a degree, it is nearly certain that the publisher or institution will have specified a particular style guide, either one of its own or one of the major guides such as CMOS, APA, or MLA. If a guide has been specified, you should follow it.

In the absence of a guide, or of an appropriate rule in the guide specified, I would treat this as a multi-paragraph block quotation. Most style guides specify that such a quotation should be indented on both the right and on  the left, and that no quotation marks should be used. But if the specified guide has a different rule for block quotations, follow that rule. Of course the source should be properly attributed.